# SP2013 Community site members - some links to profile pictures use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: 2013, user-profile, https

Using SharePoint 2013, I created web application for MySite and another web application named Portal for team sites, communities and other content.

I set up SSL for both web apps (HTTPS only, HTTP), configured profile service, search. I created some communities (as site collections in portal web application). Everything works nice except profile pictures referenced from community site (members web part) - some urls to picture use HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS. Only some of them and looks like they are mixed randomly. So in the list of community members some people have profile picture, some not

In AAM I only have default zones with public URLs on https.

How can I force profile pictures to only use HTTPS?